# Xpath not reading parameter correctly?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xpath, svg

I am trying to send a variable that is in Javascript to an XSLT template when i call it (via a parameter).

I'm calling the template from JavaScript, and I seem to be able to send the variable fine, but for some reason, when I try to use that variable in an xpath expression, it doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
var children = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].addEventListener("click", function() { onElementClick(this.id); }, false);
}

function onElementClick(id) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(<xsl:call-template name='getData'><xsl:with-param name='id'>id</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>);
}
```

Above is the code I have. As you can see, it gets an SVG element (rect) and send the id to a function when the rectangle is clicked. It then has to call a function to get the xml data associated with that rectangle ID.

XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="getData">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="//*[id[text() = $id]]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is this:

> LOG: BUS-0015
>   LOG:

The first outputs the javascript id, and the second outputs the xpath expression result. I know the xpath expression is correct, because if I set a variable manually within the template with the exact same text, it finds the expected data. I think it is maybe how it is passing it into the xsl template? But when I change the code so it just returns the value of the parameter that was passed in, it prints out the exact same thing as the previous console.log (the id).

Comment: that second console.log ... pseudo code?

Comment: Can you update with your actual code? This is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When doing JavaScript + XSLT it is a good idea to check out [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/index.html). It is a thin wrapper than makes XSLT processing using the browser's XSLT processor a breeze. On the example page, it is [demonstrated how to set parameters](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#transform).

In addition, in your snippet it is a parameter of a template. Setting stylesheet parameters from a browser means setting global parameters. For calling the entry point this makes little difference, but for this to work, you will need to declare the parameter `xsl:param` at the root level.